# How to log in automatically on the server for Meteor integration testing with a custom login handler

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, integration-testing

I'm writing integration tests for my Meteor app using Mocha and Chai. These tests are for the server functionality only.

I could fake up a Meteor user with Sinon but I would ideally like to start by logging the user in for real. However I can't work out how to do this on the server.

I'm authenticating against a remote server;

Server code:

```
Accounts.registerLoginHandler((loginRequest) => {
    if ((remoteAuthenticate(loginRequest.username, loginRequest.password)) === true) {
        // remoteAuthenticate is a function that handles login against the remote server
        ...
        // handle login success and failure
    }
});
```

This is called on the client like so:

```
Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    'methodArguments': [{
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
    }],
    'userCallback': function (err) {
        if (err) {
            Session.set('invalidCredentials', true);
        }
    },
});
```

Login from the client works fine, but I can't figure out how to call the login method directly on the server in my tests. None of the Meteor or Accounts methods seems to do this. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Did my answer brought you any further in this issue?

Comment: Hello! I am sorry, I have been on holiday and also my computer died. I will look at this when I have my dev environment back up and running. Thank you.

Comment: Did you succeed or are there any issues left that prevent you from the described intended behavior?

Comment: Sorry - I have now managed to accidentally leave the laptop in the office and I'm taking a few weeks off work! I should be able to check this in early June. I am keen to try your solution, I just haven't had access to the machine!

Comment: No worries, I'm just curious if it works for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user has already been created you can use a `DDP` connection and a package named `ongoworks:ddp-login` to authenticate from remote. It is designed to work on both, server and client.

First add the package to your project:

```
meteor add ongoworks:ddp-login
```

Then create the connection in your tests and pass it to the login call:

```
const url = https://your.server.tld
const connection = DDP.connect(url);

// describe login

it('logs in to the remote if the user exists', function (done) {
  DDP.loginWithPassword(conn, {username: 'admin'}, 'admin', function (error) {
    if (error) {
      done(error)
    } else {
      done() 
    }
  })
})
```

The `connection` instance behaves similar to your `Meteor` global, which itself has always a default connection configured by default.

For example: If you need to call methods from the remote with the logged in user you can use the `connection` instance to call the methods:

```
// describe method x
it('returns some value', function (done) {
  DDP.loginWithPassword(conn, {username: 'admin'}, 'admin', function (error) {
    // handle error...
    connection.call('method x', (err, res) => { /* handle err / res */ })
  })
})
```

Resources:

https://atmospherejs.com/ongoworks/ddp-login

https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#DDP-connect

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this to work. Your code gives me an error "Unrecognized options for login request". I used' var conn = DDP.connect(Meteor.absoluteUrl());' as per the docs. Maybe this package is not correct for my situation, as my code does not use loginWithPassword?

Comment: heh, and now I'm getting an error "TypeError: DDP.loginWithPassword is not a function" with what seems to be the same code. Note that the remote server against which I'm authenticating, is not a Meteor server, it is Active Directory.